# How to Extract String?

Tags: iphone

/common_subscriber/?content_id=4552823&**wapdld=8695411**&media_type=audio&id_class=3&section=ms_admin%2Fnewjson%2Findex__du&media_format=mobile_audio_ring_real

I want to extract "wapdld=8695411" and save it in a variable.

Comment: What programming language do you use?

Comment: Objective C, Working on iPhone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First step is find out do the seperation operation
by using `componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"`

Then again do the same with `objectatindex:1` of the array that you get after doing above operation.

And in that second array `objectAtIndex:0` will be your `wapdId=8695411`

hAPPY cODING...

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying so fast. but can u plz write the code for that.I didnt undersstood it properly

Comment: Calling `componentSeperatedByString:@"&"` on your `NSString` returns an `NSArray`, when you then call `objectAtIndex:1` on the `NSArray`, you get a new `NSString` with the content you want: `wapdId=8695411`